# Problems seeing postings/comments on other user's Facebook page

Tags: comments, facebook-wall

I have an issue with postings/comments on other users' wall/timeline not showing up. It's a user that I'm not friends with, but someone I know, who is not friend with this person either, is able to view postings/comments made on the Facebook page which makes me think this is not a question of that person's settings but my own settings perhaps.
If someone's wall is fully visible to everyone, I should be able to see the content on that page, right?